# I am using a python emulator for a project to use rubber ducky. How come the rubber ducky isn't writing anything in the Q4.py file?

Tags: python, emulation, duckyscript

This is the goal I am trying to accomplish:write a (simple) Rubber-Ducky script should write and run a Python `hello world’ script. However, since I am using macOS, I am creating a file called "Q4.py" and trying to write "Hello World!" in that python file. For reference, I was able to write my name "matt" in a .sh file with these exact files listed below, but I can't seem to get it to work for a python file.

For reference, this is my Q4.txt file which will print "Hello World!"

``DEFAULT_DELAY 500
STRING terminal
ENTER
DELAY 1000
STRING echo 'print("Hello, world!")' > /Users/matthewmcmurray/Downloads/Q4.py
ENTER
DELAY 500
STRING python3 /Users/matthewmcmurray/Downloads/Q4.py
ENTER

The following below are my files for the python emulator:

```
`**duckProcess.py:**`
`from validation import LineCheck
from time import sleep
from inputSimulator import simulate_key_press, simulate_modified_key_stroke, simulate_text_entry
import os


defaultDelay = False
defaultDelayValue = 0
lastCommand = ""
lastKey = ""
isCapsEnabled = False

def SetDelay(delay:int):
    global defaultDelay
    global defaultDelayValue

    if delay > 1:
        defaultDelay = True
    defaultDelayValue = delay

def ReadFile(filePath:str):
    f = open(filePath)
    duckyFile = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()

    for line in duckyFile:
        Calculate(line)
    
    sleep(5) 

    if os.path.exists('/Users/tyran/Desktop/DuckyQ3.sh'):
        print("File created successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to create the file.")


    for line in duckyFile:
        Calculate(line)

def Calculate(line:str):
    command, keys = ProcessLine(line)
    KeyboardAction(command, keys)

def CheckDefaultSleep():
    if defaultDelay:
        sleep(defaultDelayValue / 1000.0)

def SetLastCommand(command:str, keys:str):
    global lastCommand
    global lastKey
    lastCommand, lastKey = command, keys

def ValidateCode(filePath : str):
    f = open(filePath)
    duckyFile = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()

    for num, line in enumerate(duckyFile):
        command, keys = ProcessLine(line)
        result = LineCheck(command, keys, num+1)
        if not result:
            return False
    return True

def KeyboardAction(command:str, keys:str):
    global defaultDelay
    global defaultDelayValue
    global isCapsEnabled
    keyboardKey = keys.upper()

    try:
        match command:
            case "DEFAULT_DELAY" | "DEFAULTDELAY":
                defaultDelay = True
                defaultDelayValue += int(keys)
            case "DELAY":
                CheckDefaultSleep()
                sleep(int(keys) / 1000.0)
            case "STRING":
                CheckDefaultSleep()
                if isCapsEnabled:
                    simulate_text_entry(keys.upper())
                else:
                    file_path = "/Users/matthewmcmurray/Downloads/Q3.sh"
                    with open(file_path, "a") as file:
                        file.write("Matt\n")
            case "WINDOWS" | "GUI" | "ENTER" | "APP" | "MENU" | "SHIFT" | "ALT" | "CONTROL" | "CTRL":
                CheckDefaultSleep()
                simulate_modified_key_stroke(command, keys)
            case "TAB" | "DELETE" | "SPACE" | "DOWNARROW" | "DOWN" | "LEFTARROW" | "LEFT" | "RIGHTARROW" | "RIGHT" | "UPARROW" | "UP":
                CheckDefaultSleep()
                simulate_key_press(command)
            case "REPLAY":
                CheckDefaultSleep()
                for _ in range(int(keys)):
                    KeyboardAction(lastCommand, lastKey)
            case "CAPS":
                CheckDefaultSleep()
                isCapsEnabled = not isCapsEnabled
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    if command != "REPLAY" and command != "REM":
        SetLastCommand(command, keys)

def ProcessLine(line):
    words = line.split(' ')
    command = words[0].upper()  # Convert to uppercase for consistent matching
    keys = " ".join(words[1:])
    return command, keys



# Testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    '''KeyboardAction("DEFAULT_DELAY", "100")
    KeyboardAction("STRING", "I am a bumbling fool")
    KeyboardAction("WINDOWS", "")
    KeyboardAction("DELAY", "1000")
    KeyboardAction("WINDOWS", "")
    KeyboardAction("ENTER", "")

    KeyboardAction("SHIFT", "GUI")
    KeyboardAction("SHIFT", "UPARROW")
    KeyboardAction("REPLAY", "5")
    KeyboardAction("SHIFT", "DOWNARROW")
    KeyboardAction("SHIFT", "LEFTARROW")
    KeyboardAction("SHIFT", "RIGHTARROW")
    KeyboardAction("SHIFT", "p")
    ''' # This much is confirmed to work correctly

    ValidateCode("helloworld.txt")`


`**inputSimulator.py:**`
`from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from time import sleep

keyboard = Controller()

keys = {
    "DELETE": Key.delete,
    "SHIFT": Key.shift,
    "CONTROL": Key.ctrl,
    "CTRL": Key.ctrl,
    "ENTER": Key.enter,
    "HOME": Key.home,
    "PAGEUP": Key.page_up,
    "PAGEDOWN": Key.page_down,
    "UPARROW": Key.up,
    "UP": Key.up,
    "LEFTARROW": Key.left,
    "LEFT": Key.left,
    "RIGHTARROW": Key.right,
    "RIGHT": Key.right,
    "DOWNARROW": Key.down,
    "DOWN": Key.down,
    "TAB": Key.tab,
    "ESCAPE": Key.esc,
    "ESC": Key.esc,
    "ALT": Key.alt,
    "END": Key.end,
    "SPACE": " ",  # Space key for macOS
    "GUI": Key.cmd,  # Command key for macOS
}

def simulate_modified_key_stroke(modifier_key, key):
    if key in keys:
        keyboard.press(keys[modifier_key])
        keyboard.press(keys[key])
        keyboard.release(keys[key])
        keyboard.release(keys[modifier_key])

def simulate_key_press(key):
    if key in keys:
        keyboard.press(keys[key])
        keyboard.release(keys[key])

def simulate_text_entry(text, delay=13/1000.0):
    for char in text:
        sleep(delay)
        if char in keys:
            keyboard.press(keys[char])
            keyboard.release(keys[char])
        else:
            keyboard.press(char)
            keyboard.release(char)

def text_to_keycode(*args):
    result = []
    for string in args:
        if string.upper() in keys:
            string = keys[string.upper()]
        result.append(string)
    return result`

`
**main.py:**`
`import argparse
from duckProcess import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Testing out the main.')

    #args = parser.parse_args()

    filePath = input("Input path of DuckyScript: ")
    with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline().strip()  # strip to remove any potential newline or space
        print(f"Reading command from line 1: '{first_line}'")

    
    valid = ValidateCode(filePath)

    if valid:
        npt = input("Script has been validated. Execute? (Y/n) : ")
        if npt == "Y" or npt == "y":
            ReadFile(filePath)`

`**validation.py**`
`from time import sleep

validFKeys = ["F" + str(x) for x in range(1,13)]
validShiftKeys = ["DELETE", "HOME", "INSERT", "PAGEUP", "PAGEDOWN", "WINDOWS", "GUI", "UPARROW", "LEFTARROW", "RIGHTARROW", "TAB"]
validCTRLkeys = ["BREAK", "PAUSE", "ESCAPE", "ESC"]
validAltKeys = ["ALT", "END", "ESC", "ESCAPE", "SPACE", "TAB"]

def LineCheck(command:str, keys:str, currentLine:int):
    match command:
        case "REM":
            pass
        case "STRING":
            if len(keys) <= 0:
                print("Empty STRING command on line " + str(currentLine) + ".\n"
                      "This won't cause any errors, but it will not type anything.")
        case "DEFAULT_DELAY" | "DEFAULTDELAY":
            if not keys.isnumeric():
                print(f"ERROR [Line = {currentLine}] |:: DEFAULTDELAY only accepts integer values.")
                return False
            elif currentLine != 1:
                print(f"ERROR [Line = {currentLine}] |:: DEFAULTDELAY should only be present on line 1.")
                return False
        case "DELAY":
            if not keys.isnumeric():
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: DELAY only accepts integer values.".format(line=currentLine))
        case "GUI":
            if keys not in ["space", "r", ""]:  # Add other acceptable keys if needed
                print(f"ERROR [Line = {currentLine}] |:: Argument following GUI is not valid.")
                return False
        case "ENTER":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following ENTER. ENTER function doesn't support key combos.".format(line=currentLine))
        case "APP" | "MENU":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following APP/MENU, which don't support key combos.".format(line=currentLine))
        case "SHIFT":
            if len(keys) > 0 and keys not in validShiftKeys:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: Command following SHIFT is not valid.".format(line=currentLine))
        case "ALT":
            if len(keys) > 0 and keys not in validAltKeys:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: Command following ALT is not valid.".format(line=currentLine))
        case "CONTROL" | "CTRL":
            if keys not in validCTRLkeys and keys not in validFKeys and len(keys) == 1 and not keys.isalpha():
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: Command following {command} is not valid.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "TAB":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "DOWNARROW" | "DOWN":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "LEFTARROW" | "LEFT":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "RIGHTARROW" | "RIGHT":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "UPARROW" | "UP":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "REPLAY":
            if not keys.isnumeric():
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: REPLAY only accepts integers.".format(line=currentLine))
        case "DELETE":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "CAPS":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine, command=command))
        case "SPACE":
            if len(keys) > 0:
                print("ERROR [Line = {line}] |:: There is a command following {command}.".format(line=currentLine,command=command))
                return False
        case _:
            print(f"ERROR [Line = {currentLine}] |:: Command '{command}' not recognized.")
            return False
    return True
```

when running "python3 main.py", it asked me for the input file as expected, "Input path of DuckyScript:", and i inputted Q4.txt. It went through and processed each line, and completed, but at the end the Q4.py file was not updated to have 'Hello World!' in it. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated!

For more information, my Q4.py is a file in my Downloads directory, and my WorkingPrototype2 folder with the file in it is inside of the Downloads directory as well.